# How to chang the directory of the IsolatedStorage Cache with Enterprise Library?

Tags: caching, enterprise-library, isolatedstorage

I'm using MS Entlib 5.0 to manage cache, but I find it's very complicated to deploy my Web Site because it usually told me that I can't create the storage directory.

How to modify the directory where the data is stored? (I use IsolatedStorage)

like: `(dir="d:/cacheData")` in a config file?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of isolated storage is that the system manages the location, not you. So you can't change the directory if you're using the Isolated Storage cache manager.